# Как получить ключи и значения по индексу из Map в Dart?

Tags: map, dart

Я хочу получить ключи и значение по индексу, но я не могу понять как это можно реализовать смотрел решения на других языках ничего не понял, буду глубоко признателен если сможете помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` в `Dart` является `Key-Value Pair` - где каждый элемент имеет ключ и значение. Благодаря свойствам `Key` и `Value`, которые есть у данной коллекции, мы можем получить ключ и значение элемента. Но чтобы работать эффективные я предлагаю использовать другой вид коллекции, а именно `List<T>`. В нем намного больше возможностей в отличие от `Map`, но также есть и недостатки: `Map` намного быстрее обрабатывает значения **в маленькой коллекции** чем `List`, но чем больше коллекция тем медленнее начинает обрабатываться `Map`.

@Михаил Ребров, уже дал ответ как можно решить ваш вопрос. Я в свою очередь покажу пример как можно использовать связку `Map` и `List`. (Естественно dynamic используется для примера, и рекомендуется сделать строгую типизацию)

```
void main(){
  // Создаем List с нашей структурой
  List<ListStructure> list = new List<ListStructure>();

  // Создаем Map и заполняем List значениями Map
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = {
        "1": "Tom",
        "2": "Bob",
        "3": "Sam"
    }..forEach((k,v) => list.add(new ListStructure(k, v)));

  // Выводим List поэлементно (по индексу)
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    print("${list[i].key}: ${list[i].values}");
  }

  print("");

  // добавим в List новый элемент
  list.add(new ListStructure("4","Kail"));

  // присвоим Map значения List
  map = list.asMap();

  // Выводим Map поэлементно (по индексу)
  for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
    print("${map[i].key}: ${map[i].values}");
  }
}

// Структура List
class ListStructure{
  dynamic key;
  dynamic values;

  ListStructure(this.key, this.values);
}
```

Вывод:

```
1: Tom
2: Bob
3: Sam

1: Tom
2: Bob
3: Sam
4: Kail
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у нас есть `Map<K,V>`, где 
`K` - это тип ключа, 
а `V` - это тип значения.

Что мы можем сделать?
У экземпляра `Map<K,V>`, есть свойства:

- `keys`, которые хранять `Iterable<K>`, в которых лежат ключи
- `values`, которые хранять `Iterable<V>`, в которых лежат значения

Что более примечательно, у экземпляра `Map<K,V>`, есть свойство `entries`, которое хранит в себе `Iterable<MapEntry<K,V>>`, в котором лежат вхождения `Map`.
Наблюдательный читатель, конечно же заметит, что я говорю об `Iterable`, который конечно же можно проитерировать, но нельзя получить значение по индексу.
Безусловно это так, но у экземпляра абстрактного класса `Iterable`, есть метод `toList()`, который приводит данный экземпляр к обычному списку, из которого уже можно получить элемент по индексу, с помощью метода `elementAt()`.

Итого:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {

  var map = Map<String, String>();

  map = {
    'one': '1',
    'two': '2',
    'three': '3'
  };

  // получаем и сохраняем в отдельную переменную список вхождений
  var entries = map.entries.toList();
  print('Вывод данных полученных из списка вхождений:');
  print(entries.elementAt(0).key + ': ' + entries.elementAt(0).value);
  print(entries.elementAt(1).key + ': ' + entries.elementAt(1).value);
  print(entries.elementAt(2).key + ': ' + entries.elementAt(2).value);


  // получаем и сохраняем в отдельные переменные список ключей и список значений
  var keys = map.keys.toList();
  var values = map.values.toList();

  print('Вывод данных полученных отдельно из списка ключей и из списка значений:');
  print(keys.elementAt(0) + ':' + values.elementAt(0));
  print(keys.elementAt(1) + ':' + values.elementAt(1));
  print(keys.elementAt(2) + ':' + values.elementAt(2));

}
```

Вывод:

```
Вывод данных полученных из списка вхождений:
one: 1
two: 2
three: 3
Вывод данных полученных отдельно из списка ключей и из списка значений:
one:1
two:2
three:3
```

Вроде, как все правильно.
Пользуйтесь, на здоровье.